# Name of data structure where each node has [0, n] known children and [0, 1] unknown parents?

Tags: data-structures, recursive-datastructures

As always, a diagram explains this much better than words:

[image: Diagram of data structure]

A node may or may not have a parent. A node may only have a single parent, so [0, 1] parents. It does not store any information about the parent, so a node doesn't know if it has a parent.

A node may or not have any children. A node may have as many children as it wants, so [0, n] children. It stores information regarding how to reach each of its child nodes.

Is there a particular term for this type of data structure? It's essentially a linked list with multiple children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a *forest*, that is, a collection of *trees*. (In a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) there is only *one* parentless node, which is called the *root*.)

A forest not at all like a linked list; first of all, because there are potentianly multiple parentless nodes, it's a collection; and second, because a node can have multiple descendants, traversing a tree is quite different from traversing a list, growing a tree can happen in many ways, and in general trees offer many interesting options which lists don't.

P.S. The diagram in the question shows one tree. The text of the question does not say that there is only one parentless node, and this is why the described data structure is a forest. If it is guaranteed that no more than one node is parentless then the data structure is a tree.

Comment: I think forest is what I'm looking for. For accepting this answer, can you tell me if having this structure be directed still means its a forest? [Wikipedia says a forest is an undirected graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Forest)

Comment: Regarding the P.S.: yes, there would be multiple diagrams in addition to the one I've shown. I should've put another node next to it with one parent and no children next to it to clarify this

Comment: The words "tree" and "forest" as used when referring to data structures have related but different meanings from those in graph theory. Check the Wikipedia articles on "[Tree (data structure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))" and "[Tree (graph theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory))". A node in a data structure tree has a parent and descendants; a node in a graph theory tree has neighbours. A data structure tree is inherently directional, from the root to the leaves; a graph theory tree is usually undirected and unrooted.